# When does the minimum of: $\int_0^1 f^2(x) dx - 2\lambda \int_0^1 x f(x) dx + \frac{\lambda^2}{3}$ occur?

Tags: integration, derivatives

When does the minimum of: $\displaystyle{\int_0^1 f^2(x) dx - 2\lambda \int_0^1 x f(x) dx + \frac{\lambda^2}{3}}$ occur?

I have no clue, other than this looks like a quadratic.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a quadratic because it is a quadratic:
\begin{align}
0\le\int_0^1(f-\lambda x)^2&=\int_0^1f^2-2\lambda\int_0^1xf+\lambda^2\int_0^1x^2\\
&=\int_0^1f^2-2\lambda\int_0^1xf+\lambda^2\cdot \frac{1}{3}.
\end{align}

So the minimum is $0$ and it is attained when $f(x)=\lambda x$.

Comment: It is actually possible to explicitly say what $\lambda$ here should be in the integral form.